# Reopen request: Allowing logo variations question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I think this question should be reopened: [Variation of umbrella logo for "children's" department](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54558/variation-of-umbrella-logo-for-childrens-department)

There's no question in my mind that it's an on-topic issue/question, and comes up with respect to corporate-identity programs all the time.  I must have done and later modified a dozen identity programs when I was doing commercial art for a living.

Comment: Do you mind linking to the question?  No clue which one you're referring to.

Comment: ah, bugger!  It showed up in the sidebar and I didn't notice that it was closed 20 months ago!    I thought it was brand-new and easily found.   But it's still (imo) a very valid and narrow question and could bear being discussed.  It's at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54558/variation-of-umbrella-logo-for-childrens-department

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with reopening the question as it currently stands. [DA01's comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54558/variation-of-umbrella-logo-for-childrens-department#comment79496_54558) covers the reason well:

> It's impossible to say generically. It all depends on the particulars of your company, strategy, audience, and, of course, the logo itself. Plenty of companies stick with one logo across all products. Other companies create all sorts of variations for each individual audience.

While it may be decideable for a particular company/logo, it likely isn't always the same answer for *every* company/logo. To answer this question well also takes knowing the company and usage pretty well, as well as the possible variations and purposes, none of which we have in that question.

Comment: Note, however, that her question is about whether to fight to  maintain the existing program unchanged.  The answer to that does not depend on our knowing anything about the corporation because the answer is "no, because you might as well fight to stop the tides".  The discussion would then be how to analyse the current identity program and integrate changes that *fit*.  It's a difficult problem and well worth discussion.

Comment: The distinction you're making isn't very clear to me

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a fine question. At the same time though it's over a year old and got closed by community members not a mod. If it gets views to reopen or you want to edit it to be a little more focused I'd open it up. Until then though I'm not inclined to open it without the support of the community at large.